# Why does GNOME contacts only import a small number of my Google contacts?

Tags: debian, gnome

I have `1006` contacts in my Google contacts and after I add my Google account under GNOME's *Settings > Online Accounts* (I made sure I am syncing everything).

[image]

my GNOME contacts manages to sync just around `100` contacts. I also made sure that my Google account's address book is selected in GNOME contacts.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed those contacts exist at https://contacts.google.com/ ?

Comment: I did. They are all there. I am one of the rare Google users who really have contacts sorted out. My every contact has a profile image etc...

Comment: I don't use gnome unfortunately to test this. Hold on let me get my virtual machine configured

Comment: The software works for me. I tested a few hundred contracts. It's worth noting this is part of the software Gnome Contacts which uses GNOME Online Accounts. It might well be a bug.

Comment: It surely is...

Comment: It sucks because you're dealing with a cloud service and private data. Makes it pretty hard to debug.